# Git log, how can I list commits excluding those that were later merged with another?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-log

I would like to get a list of git commits, including merges but excluding those commits that were later merged with a parallel commit. Here's an example, expressed in Tortoise Git's commit graph (G is the earliest commit, A the latest):

[image: example git log with annotation]

I would like to get a list of those revision that have been labeled with a letter (A to G) here. The reason is simply that they seem like good representative states to look at when exploring the history of the project.

As a side question, I would also like to know how to get a list of all the black nodes.

I'm hoping to find a git-command, or simple command line, that works in both linux and windows. I've tried a number of git-log flags but didn't find one that does what I want.

Comment: There is the `--first-parent` option for `git log` which does something like that, but I don't think it's exactly what you describe.

Comment: I think it gives me all the black nodes, i.e., the answer to the side question.